# which gsettings schema controls "show my login name in the menu bar"?

Tags: gsettings

I would like to script the enabling of Ubuntu's "show my login name in the menu bar". The checkbox lives in the GUI under System Settings > User Accounts.

I assume this can be scripted using gsettings. I've grep'd gsettings get-schemas for the obvious terms (user, menu, account), but no keys within those schemas look promising.

I've also used gsettings monitor on promisingly-named schemas while toggling the checkbox in the UI; no luck.

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show name:

```
settings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel true
```

Hide name:

```
settings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel false
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm leaving this comment only to help future searchers: the command is `gsettings` with a 'g'